# Lower the difficulty level on a captcha zend form element?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, recaptcha

I am using reCaptcha with zend form, like this:

```
    $recaptcha = new Zend_Service_ReCaptcha('xxx', 'yyy',
        NULL, array('theme' => 'white'));

    $captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha',
        array(
            'label'          => 'Type the characters you see in the picture below.',
            'captcha'        =>  'ReCaptcha',
            'captchaOptions' => array(
                'captcha' => 'ReCaptcha',
                'service' => $recaptcha
            )
        )
    );
```

I am wondering if there is a setting to make it less difficult for people to read the words. it just seems to hard to decipher those words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a note under it saying "do your best".

In each re-captcha there is one simple and one hard word. If you type the simple one, you almost get it. If you do your best for the hard word, chances are that someone already typed the same as you do. Google (behind re-captcha) consider an answer valid if at least 3 users have already given it.

Answer (score 3):

No; ReCaptcha does not have a difficulty setting.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your captcha question but have you thought about using some other 'human testing' method?  Captcha, IMHO, makes forms harder to use for the end user which is never a good thing.  I personally like using timers on my forms.  I set a variable to time() when the page loads and on submit, the variable is checked against the current time and if the form was submitted in say, less than 2 or 3 seconds, its probably a bot.  There are also many other and better ways around 'human testing' than captchas.

Answer (score 1):

There are not settings for difficulty level on ReCaptcha. Period.

I do not use it, and I also do not recommend anyone using it.

Ask answers of mathematical questions like 2 + 2, that way, you will not just have humans coming in. Also, questions like when is the independence day? is not so good questions since you will have visitors from across the globe. Use maths.